# Prove: $\forall A,B(A-B=\emptyset \implies A\subset B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Lemma:** $A-B=\emptyset\implies A\subset A\cap B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets.

*Proof (lemma).* Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets and assume $A-B=\emptyset$. Pursuant to the axiom of extensionality our premise means
$$\forall x\in A-B(x\in \emptyset)\wedge \forall x'\in\emptyset(x'\in A-B)$$

Since there's no $y$ for which $y\in \emptyset$, we'll point out that in accordance with the foregoing statement there must be some $x$ such that $x\notin A \vee x\in B$.

With a view to show $A\subset (A\cap B)$ let $a\in A$. By choosing $x=a$, $$a\notin A \vee a\in B$$

From this foregoing statement certainly $a\in B$. Then, thus far $\forall a\in A(a\in A\cap B)$ or simply $$A\subset(A\cap B)$$

*Proof.*  Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Subsequently,$$A\subset (A\cap B)\subset B$$ provided $A-B=\emptyset$.

**Question:** Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using Reductio ad absurdum.

The hypothesis means ( since " equality amounts to reciprocal inclusion")  : for all x, in case  x is in A and not in B, then x belongs to the empty set.

Now, suppose ( for refutation) that A is not included in B.

It means there is some object $a$ that belongs to A, but not to B.

The universal rule admitted as hypothesis applies to  this object $a$.

So $a$ belongs to the empty set, which is absurd.

So, A is included in B.